# Restart text colors configuration of own eclipse editor plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, editor

I created a new eclipse editor plugin and set the colors like this page and code:
http://www.realsolve.co.uk/site/tech/jface-text.php

```
public XMLEditor()
{
    super();
    colorManager = new ColorManager();
    setSourceViewerConfiguration(new XMLConfiguration(colorManager));
    setDocumentProvider(new XMLDocumentProvider());
}
```

Now, I created a new preference page to change the colors. After change the colors in this page, I set a new SourceViewerConfiguration for editor but the colors not change.

If I close and reopen the Editor, the colors change.
Someone knows some method to reset or restart the editor. Or some method to update the SourceViewerConfiguration and the colors?

Answer (score 0):

I managed with this code, but Its stop to work some alias, like "CTRL + Z":

```
    configuration = new XMLConfiguration(colorManager);
    setSourceViewerConfiguration(configuration);

    ProjectionViewer viewer = (ProjectionViewer) getSourceViewer();
    try {
        viewer.configure(configuration);
    } catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException e) {
        // Empty
    }
```